# MySQL won't profile queries that include user-defined functions?

Tags: mysql, profiling

I've noticed that, when using query profiling, it won't profile queries that contain user defined functions. Can anyone confirm this or have an insight as to why? I can't find any documentation online that corroborates this.

I'm on a shared MySQL server running version 5.1.56

I use: `SET profiling = 1;` and `SHOW PROFILES;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have encountered this bug; http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=61328

There is a good write up on defined function profiling with a link to a patch at the MYSQL Performance blob; http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=61328